# Find availability percentage- software architecture

Tags: architecture, software-design, availability

I was trying to solve the following question in software architecture.

> A software system crashed 20 times in an year and for each crash, it
>   takes 2 minutes to restart. Calculate availability in that year

I used the formula MTBF/(MTBF+MTTR). How can I calculate MTBF and availability. Please help!

I did it like

> MTBF = 365*24*60-40/ 20
>   MTTR = 2*20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTBF in days is 365 / 20 (I don't think it makes any sense to take the 2 minutes recovery time into account here but your teacher might have a different opinion.)

Availability in minutes is: (minutes-per-year - 20 * 2) / minutes-per-year. It is common to write this value as a percentage, so you might multiply it with 100.

As a general advice, try to understand what these values *mean*, then the formulas will become evident.